# Showing that $F$ is a uniformly continuous real-valued function on $C(S)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Definitions:
$C(S) = \{f: f \text{ is bounded, continuous and real-valued function on }S\}$

with metric
$$d(f,g) = \sup\{|f(x) - g(x)| : x\in S \}$$

Problem:

Consider $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. For a fixed $s_0 \in S$, define $F(f) = f(s_0)$. Show $F$ is a uniformly continuous real-valued function on the metric space $C(S)$.

Therefore, we need to show that

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \ \exists \delta > 0 : f,g \in C(S) \ \land \ d(f,  g) < \delta \Rightarrow \ |F(f) - F(g)| < \epsilon$$

From the definition of the metric

$$|F(f) - F(g)| = |f(s_0)-g(s_0)| \leq \sup\{|f(x) - g(x)| : x\in S\} = d(f,g) < \delta$$

Let

$$\epsilon = \delta$$

Therefore,
$$\text{if } d(f,g) < \delta \Rightarrow |F(f) - F(g)| < \delta = \epsilon$$

Comment: This is fine. Why do you even doubt this?

Comment: My problem is at the end when I have to define $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. I am just not sure of how to define them for any case.

Comment: $\delta =\epsilon$ works fine here.